# Sorting std::list using std::set

Tags: c++, stl

I'm adding two different elements to both std::list and std::set and I want the std::list to be sorted with the same order as of std::set. one way I tried is when the element is added to std::set, find that element then get the index of that element using std::distance(begin, found) and then insert the element to that index in std::list. is there any other way?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? There may be a better overall solution to your problem rather than finding a may to keep a list and set synchronised.

Comment: just keep the std::set and when you need the std:: list you create it from the std::set.

Comment: std::set contains a 'key' and std::list contains a value related to the key. In that case i think using std::map would be a better idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the [std::map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/), with the data you put in the set as key, and the data you put in the list as value.

This way your list elements will be ordered.

Answer (score 0):

It is too complicated a way! 
In fact std::set implemented as binary tree, and uses std::less for sorting (by default). Also this provides "stable" iterator, it is mean that iterator returned by std::set::insert will be valid until element explicitly erased. So you can put just inserted iterator to std::list.
And wise verse - std::list has also stable iterator, so you can put items to list but place iterators to set. In last way just override std::less